# scheme/racket: breaking a list into list of lists

Tags: scheme, racket

If i have a list with 3 distinct objects that are separated from each other with an all uppercase string, how do i bundle them into a list of 3 lists?

I've only gotten so far as

```
#lang racket

(define (test-string4 lst keyword)
  (let ((kw (string-upcase keyword)))
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((string-upper-case? (car lst))
           (list
```

For a list of '("POLYLINE" "2" "3" ... "LINE" "2" "3" ...)
it should be broken down into '(("POLYLINE" "2" "3" ...) ("LINE" "2" "3" ...))

Comment: Could you provide an example (input and expected output)?

Comment: Sure, i've done so in my edit!

Comment: What is the point of `keyword`?  You don't seem to use it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `string-upper-case?` has already been defined (say, using [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29)):

```
(define (string-upper-case? str)
  (andmap char-upper-case?
          (string->list str)))
```

… We can write a generic, simpler, arguably more idiomatic implementation using [`break`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#break) from SRFI-1 to split a list into sublists with elements that start with a given condition, in this case being an all-uppercase string:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (splitter pred? lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (let-values ([(data tail) (break pred? (rest lst))])        
        (cons (cons (first lst) data)
              (splitter pred? tail)))))
```

It doesn't matter how long each sequence of elements is, we don't even have to pass a list of keywords as long as we respect the convention that keywords are all-uppercase strings. For example:

```
(splitter string-upper-case?
          '("POLYLINE" "2" "3" "4" "LINE" "2" "3" "TEST" "1"))

=> '(("POLYLINE" "2" "3" "4") ("LINE" "2" "3") ("TEST" "1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want, although `string-upper-case?` does not appear to be defined in racket.

```
(define (splitter lst curr)
  (cond ((null? lst)  ; Put current "object" in a list
         (cons curr '()))

        ((string-upper-case? (car lst)) ; Starting a new "object"
         (let ((rslt (splitter (cdr lst) (list (car lst)))))
           (if (null? curr)
               rslt ; This is the only object
               (cons curr rslt)))) ; Add last-finished object to front of result

        (else ; Continue w/ current "object"
         (splitter (cdr lst) (append curr (list (car lst)))))))

(define (test-string4 lst)
  (splitter lst '()))
```

Comment: In Scheme the convention is using `else`, not `#t` for the last condition.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether your data structure is really appropriate for your needs, but here we go:

First we'll define `take-right-until` which will split off the right-most sublist according to a predicate `f`:

```
(define (take-right-until lst f)
  (let loop ((spl1 (reverse lst)) (spl2 null) (found #f))
    (if (or found (null? spl1))
        (values (reverse spl1) spl2)
        (let ((c (car spl1)))
          (loop (cdr spl1) (cons c spl2) (f c))))))
```

testing:

```
> (take-right-until '("POLYLINE" "2" "3" "LINE" "4" "5" ) (curryr member '("POLYLINE" "LINE")))
'("POLYLINE" "2" "3")
'("LINE" "4" "5")
> (take-right-until '("POLYLINE" "2" "3") (curryr member '("POLYLINE" "LINE")))
'()
'("POLYLINE" "2" "3")
```

and then `test-string4`:

```
(define (test-string4 lst kwds)
  (define kw (map string-upcase kwds))
  (define f (curryr member kw))
  (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
    (if (null? lst)
        res
        (let-values (((spl1 spl2) (take-right-until lst f)))
          (loop spl1 (cons spl2 res))))))
```

testing:

```
> (test-string4 '("POLYLINE" "2" "3" "LINE" "4" "5" ) '("polyline" "line"))
'(("POLYLINE" "2" "3") ("LINE" "4" "5"))
> (test-string4 '("POLYLINE" "2" "3" "LINE" "4" "5" "SQUARE" "6" "7" "8") '("polyline" "square" "line"))
'(("POLYLINE" "2" "3") ("LINE" "4" "5") ("SQUARE" "6" "7" "8"))
```